# Circle supposed to move when you click on it but disappearing instead

Tags: python, python-turtle

For a classwork assignment everyone in the class had to make a program where when you click the shape it will disappear then reappear in a different location. However, it just disappears in mine.  My teacher looked over it and saw no issues, but I still can't figure out how to fix it. Here is the code I wrote:

```
#-----import statements-----
import turtle as trtl
import random as rand
#-----game configuration----
dizzy_color = "red"
dizzy_size = 3
dizzy_shape = "circle"
#-----initialize turtle-----
dizzy = trtl.Turtle()
dizzy.shape(dizzy_shape)
dizzy.shapesize(dizzy_size)
dizzy.fillcolor(dizzy_color)
#-----game functions--------
def change_position():
  new_xpos = rand.randint(-100, 100)
  new_ypos = rand.randint(-50, 50)
  dizzy.penup()
  dizzy.hideturtle()
  goto(new_xpos,new_ypos)
  dizzy.showturtle()
  dizzy.pendown()
def dizzy_clicked(x,y): 
  change_position()
#-----events----------------
dizzy.onclick(dizzy_clicked)
wn = trtl.Screen()
wn.mainloop()
```

Also the Turtle's name is dizzy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you called the `goto()` method but forgot the object:

```
goto(new_xpos,new_ypos)
```

It should be:

```
dizzy.goto(new_xpos,new_ypos)
```

If you, or your teacher, are using a proper Python programming environment, you should have seen the related error message:

```
NameError: name 'goto' is not defined
```

Here's how I would go about writing this program:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

DIZZY_COLOR = 'red'
DIZZY_SIZE = 3
DIZZY_SHAPE = 'circle'

def change_position():
    new_xpos = randint(-100, 100)
    new_ypos = randint(-50, 50)

    dizzy.hideturtle()
    dizzy.goto(new_xpos, new_ypos)
    dizzy.showturtle()

def dizzy_clicked(x, y):
    dizzy.onclick(None)  # disable handler inside handler
    change_position()
    dizzy.onclick(dizzy_clicked)

screen = Screen()

dizzy = Turtle()
dizzy.penup()
dizzy.shape(DIZZY_SHAPE)
dizzy.shapesize(DIZZY_SIZE)
dizzy.fillcolor(DIZZY_COLOR)
dizzy.onclick(dizzy_clicked)

screen.mainloop()
```